# Using class method to search list of objects - python

Tags: python, list, class, object, methods

I'm trying to search a list of objects (employees) using this function. Basically, the user can input an employee ID # and then I want to use that ID to see if any of the employee's ID #'s match and return all variables of the object that it matches. I thought this would do what I needed but something isn't quite right. Any thoughts?

```
def getByID(employees, eid):
    readFile(employees)
    for x in employees:
        y = x.getEmployeeID
        if y == eid:
            return x.printObject()
```

Comment: You are returning in the first match, do you want all matches? Also what isn't quite right?

Comment: EID's are unique to each employee so only one should match, but when I run this code I don't receive any matches and nothing gets returned even though I am entering an ID I know an employee has.

Comment: What are the types of y and eid, could add a small data sample?

Comment: Whats you write for `eid`, and also if you put `print(y)` in the loop what would be the result?

Comment: getEmployeeID method returns int(self.__employeeID). EID being input is of type int. If I place print(y) in the loop it returns <bound method Employee.getEmployeeID of <__main__.Employee object at 0x039B6210>> for all 7 employees (each Employee object being different of course)

Comment: @Jenkins Is my answer good now?

Comment: Yes, all good! Thank you!

Comment: @Jenkins Please upvote if you want :-)

Comment: @Jenkins Happy to help, :-), 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only returning the first match, because `return` only executes and evaluates once, so you may well need to do (the below returns a list), also have to call `getEmployeeID`:

```
def getByID(employees, eid):
    l=[]
    readFile(employees)
    for x in employees:
        y = x.getEmployeeID()
        if y == eid:
            l.append(x.printObject())
    return l
```